# Style tfooter with pagination using Bootstrap Angular6 Datatable

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I used angular 6 datatable to paginate my data in table.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable

Everything works fine but i cant deal with style in footer of mfBootstrapPaginator

[image]
As you can see, this items are not in one line. How to set them in one line or at least next to each other?

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-bordered" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <!-- I got 8 columns in my project -->
        <td colspan="8">
          <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25, 50, 100]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

I use Angular 6, Bootstrap 4

Comment: If possible can you make a StackBlitz and put your code in there so We can help you further

Comment: I'm the same problem...Have do you resolve it?  @davecar21

Comment: @cwiq doyou resolve it?

Comment: Try to put your code in  [http://plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) or [https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: @Doflamingo19 no i didn't. I just changed whole table. I chose material one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the display of the pagination class:

```
.pagination {
   display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now, the question is older but maybe it helps someone. I wrote this:

```html
<style>
  ul.pagination {display: inline-flex !important;}
  .pagination li.active .page-link {background-color: rgb(54,61,71) !important; border-color: rgb(54,61,71) !important;}
</style>
```

in my index.html befor the head close tag and it works for me. I hope it helps someone.